# How to restrict an SSH key to certain IP addresses?

Tags: ssh

I want to be able to log in to a (publicly-accessible) SSH server from the local network (192.168.1.*) using some SSH key, but I don't want that key to be usable from outside the local network.
I want some other key to be used for external access instead (same user in both cases).

Is such a thing possible to achieve in SSH?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223592/30851

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow direct root access via SSH on certain IP range?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223586/how-to-allow-direct-root-access-via-ssh-on-certain-ip-range)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz: It's not a duplicate question, the answer just happens to be the same. It's key-specific so it's not at all obvious that the same solution applies (I would've expected that answer to involve `sshd_config` instead).

Comment: @Ulrich - one of the answers there solves this (different) problem, but the other is unrelated.  The question is definitely different.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes.

In the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server, each entry now probably looks like

```
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZSOMEKEYFINGERPRINT comment
```

(or similar)

There is an optional first column that may contain options.  These are described in the `sshd` manual.

One of the options is

```
from="pattern-list"
```

> Specifies that in addition to public key authentication, either
>                the canonical name of the remote host or its IP address must be
>                present in the comma-separated list of patterns.  See PATTERNS in
>                ssh_config(5) for more information on patterns.
>
> In addition to the wildcard matching that may be applied to
>                hostnames or addresses, a from stanza may match IP addresses
>                using CIDR address/masklen notation.
>
> The purpose of this option is to optionally increase security:
>                public key authentication by itself does not trust the network or
>                name servers or anything (but the key); however, if somebody
>                somehow steals the key, the key permits an intruder to log in
>                from anywhere in the world.  This additional option makes using a
>                stolen key more difficult (name servers and/or routers would have
>                to be compromised in addition to just the key).

This means that you should be able to modify `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` from

```
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZSOMEKEYFINGERPRINT comment
```

to

```
from="pattern" ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZSOMEKEYFINGERPRINT comment
```

Where `pattern` is a pattern matching the client host that you're connecting from, for example by its public DNS name, IP address, or some network block:

```
from="192.168.1.0/24" ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZSOMEKEYFINGERPRINT comment
```

(this would only allow the use of this key from a host in the `192.168.1.*` network)

Comment: @Mehrdad Notice that `pattern` needs to match the client from the server's perspective. A local IP address pattern like `192.168.1.*` may not work (unless the server is on the same network).

Comment: Interesting, why would it not work given they are both on the same network? There's by definition no NAT involved if they're on the same network, right? (Edit: Just saw your edit. Yeah, this was specifically for the local network so it should work.)

Comment: @Mehrdad Just added that because you said the server was "publically available", so I thought it was "remote".

Comment: Ah. Nah, I mentioned that so people wouldn't start arguing with me about why disabling remote logins isn't a solution if I'm only using the server locally or something. You have to ask questions very defensively on SE in my experience... some people really go out of their way to give non-solutions. :(

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this by adding `from="192.168.1.0/24"` in front of the public key in the `.authorized_keys` file. The entire row should look like this:

```
from="192.168.1.0/24" ssh-rsa AAAA....
```